# Webpage built in bootstrap half screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site build in bootstrap 3x, while rendering in iphone the displays in half of the screen only. Here is the site [www.na2ural.com](http://www.na2ural.com). It is developed in Magento CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access website and view it on different devices with help of Google Chrome Developer Tools.

The one thing I noticed is background that is too big.

```
<img src="http://na2ural.com/skin/frontend/natural/default/images/banner.jpg" class="banner">
```

If you apply `style="max-width: 100%;"` to this image it should all be inside viewport.

Comment: Thanks @Dejan
The problem was with the video and image as you said. Fixed the issue in your way. Applied max-width to 100% for both image and video.